# How to hide the softkey bar of NOOK HD device from my application

Tags: android, hide, nook, nook-tablet

From my application, how I can hide the softkey bar of a Nook HD device ?

My application is running on full screen mode

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not hide bottom bar in NOOK HD devices.

Documentation given at [NOOK Developers site](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/22006856-nook-developer-reference-manual#_SysStatBar) says

> NOOK HD and NOOK HD+ do not support true full screen mode. The
>   bottom system bar always displays. Therefore, the NOOK "n" key is the
>   home button and not the back key since the system bar contains a back
>   key that always displays.